# Warning after didreceivememorywarning

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

During a memory warning I do the following:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


    if ([self isViewLoaded] && [self.view window] == nil) {


        self.restaurantsTableView = nil;
        self.restaurantFecther = nil;
        self.bgImageView = nil;
        self.menuFetcher = nil;
        self.searchBar = nil;
        self.searchBarDisplayContr = nil;
        self.feed = nil;
        self.searchResults = nil;
        self.locationManager = nil;
        self.restaurantsMap = nil;
        self.myImage = nil;
        self.rDetailsVC = nil;
        self.introVC = nil;
        self.SubclassVC = nil;


        self.view = nil;

    }

}
```

This seems to work fine, except that when I return to that view which all it's properties has been set to nil, plus the view, I get the following warnings:

```
The top layout guide length constraint unexpectedly lost its container. Did the application remove all constraints from the view controller's view (which would be an app error)?

The bottom layout guide length constraint unexpectedly lost its container. Did the application remove all constraints from the view controller's view (which would be an app error)?
```

How can I fix this, so I don't get those warnings and is the code above, the right way to deal with memory warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not destroy everything in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` like you have here. You should only generate non-essential bits and pieces. You especially don't want to set anything you don't explicitly create to nil, such as `self.view`.

The best way to handle this is to make each of your programmatically created views lazy-loaded, and only set them to nil if not visible on screen (IE the user is currently viewing a another view controller).

However, I doubt that your views are the memory problem here. I would worry about the data collections you have.

Answer (score 0):

Only set to nil those item that can be re-created. Then you will need to check them for nil and re-create as necessary.

Also call `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]` **after** you have released your memory.